# Apostrophe CMS slideshow singleton not accessible

Tags: node.js, jinja2, nunjucks, apostrophe-cms

I'm attempting to add an image to a page type using a `singleton` set to the `slideshow` `widgetType`

The interface is working fine (can upload image, limits uploads to the set variable), but I cannot access the object in the templates

I am logging the page object with the below script in the page template, every other custom field works fine, just not the slideshow widget.

```
var data = {{ page | json }};
console.log(data);
```

Here is what is set in app.js

```
project: {
  extend: 'apostrophe-fancy-page',
  name: 'project',
  label: 'Project',
  addFields: [
    {
      name: 'thumb',
      label: 'Thumbnail',
      type: 'singleton',
      widgetType: 'slideshow',
      options: {
        limit: 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. You don't specify, but my suspicion is that you're trying to access the thumbnail from the template for a different page that has access to it as related-page information, e.g. page.ancestors or page.children. If the singleton were being rendered on the template for the page itself, you would have no trouble with this.

The thing about related-page information is that for performance reasons, Apostrophe limits how much information it includes in those arrays.

However, you can specify that you want more information. Here is an example from the `pages` property of the `app.js` file of one of our projects:

```
pages: {
  // other config like page types goes here, then...
  ancestorOptions: {
    children: true,
    areas: [ 'thumbnail' ]
  },
  descendantOptions: {
    depth: 2,
    areas: [ 'thumbnail' ]
  }
}
```

Here we are enabling:

- Include a `.children` array for each ancestor in `page.ancestors`, for accordion nav
- Include the area called `thumbnail` for each ancestor
- Include the area called `thumbnail` for each child of the current page (`page.children`)
- Also include grandchildren `page.children[0].children` for dropdown nav

When you load more data, the price you pay is a little more time. This is a good compromise setup when you need a lot but you don't want to fetch thousands of pages and "hydrate" all of their widgets by fetching even more data.

If I'm mistaken and you are doing this on the page template for the page itself and it still doesn't work, please provide some examples and I can review those.

(I am one of the lead developers on Apostrophe. Apologies for not seeing this question sooner. StackOverflow is a good place for it and we'll be monitoring more closely in the future now that 2.0 stable has been released.)